# Getting Git GUI to Ignore Space Changes in its diff View

Tags: git, diff, git-diff, git-gui, gitk

Git comes with two default UI tools (on Windows at least): Git GUI and Gitk.

When browsing a commit, Gitk has a checkbox called "Ignore space changes" that makes the diff show only non-space related changes.

However, Git GUI always shows the *full* diff, and there is no equivalent checkbox.

Is there a way for getting Git GUI to ignore space changes too?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Answering myself...

In the Git GUI main menu go to *Edit* -> *Options*. In *Additional Diff Parameters* put `-w` (or `--ignore-all-space`).

In fact, [any other `git-diff` parameter](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) can go there too.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do this on the latest version of the gui on Mac, Edit->Options is not there any more.

Comment: @klode: Try `GitGui->Preferences...`.

Comment: exit and restart to see diff

Comment: this does not stage hunk?

Comment: @Sergei: if all hunk lines are ignored then I think not.

Comment: @AdiShavit, some bug happened, even if not all ignored it does not stage hunk sometimes. Maybe I should address it to developers of git Gui

Comment: this is fantastic, thank you